# Wordpress-URL Rewriting for pdf file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Im trying to solve an issue with one of our wordpress blogs. We have a pdf stored in a root directory of the website.

[www.mydomain.com/pdfs/mypdf.pdf](http://www.mydomain.com/pdfs/mypdf.pdf)

but all the links to that pdf in wordpress have for reasons I am as yet unsure all be made relative to the current post/tag/category etc for instance

[www.mydomain.com/blog/mypost/pds/mypdf.pdf](http://www.mydomain.com/blog/mypost/pds/mypdf.pdf)

This is causing alot of 404 errors. There a couple of hundred pages like this now, and I don't really want to manually have to go through them all. Is there something funky I could do with .htaccess to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance

Alan

I now have this.

```
RewriteRule ^urlaub_cornwall_sonderangebote\.pdf$ "http\:\/\/www\.urlaubcornwall\.de\/pdf\/urlaub_cornwall_sonderangebote\.pdf" [R=301,L]
```

Which does the job on my local machine, but not on the server, although url rewriting is definitely enabled. Any hints?

Needed to move the Rule above the standard wordpress rules for this to work. All is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you need URL rewriting here. There is simple solution - you could try to update the links in your posts table via MySQL query.
MySQL database has a handy and simple string function `REPLACE()` that allows table data with the matching string (`from_string`) to be replaced by new string (`to_string`). This is useful if there is need to search and replace a text string which affects many records or rows, such as change of company name, postcode, URL or spelling mistake.

The syntax of `REPLACE` is `REPLACE(text_string, from_string, to_string)`.

[MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) describes REPLACE as function that returns the string `text_string` with all occurrences of the string `from_string` replaced by the string `to_string`, where matching is **case-sensitive** when searching for `from_string`. The `text_string` can be retrieved from the a field in the database table too, like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'www.mydomain.com/pdfs/mypdf.pdf', 'www.mydomain.com/blog/mypost/pds/mypdf.pdf')
```

I assume that you didn`t changed the default Wordpress table names, if not so, just replace the names in the above query before copy-paste.

Comment: Thank you, but I should have added I don't have access to the database.